# How do I create a component both - A kafka consumer and a kafka Producer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am trying to create a component which consumes data from one topic, processes it and sends to another topic, i.e., I need to make my component a consumer and producer both.
How do I configure this in my Spring boot application?

Comment: Just look for some tutorial online...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you are looking for is the Kafka Streams API.
It's an Open source Java API for manipulating events in flight by reading from one topic, run through processing steps and writing to another topic.
Therefore it acts as both a producer and consumer.
See [Kafka Streams documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/) for examples.

Setting different Serde configs for the producer and consumer:

```
 KStream<String, String> wordCountInputStream = streamsBuilder.stream("word-count-input", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String()));
        KTable<String, Long> wordCounts = wordCountInputStream.mapValues(value -> value.toLowerCase()).....

        wordCounts.toStream().to("word-count-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. Yes, I am using Kafka streams. I am just unable to understand how to give the producer/consumer configuration. As in, how do we set the configuration for both using the same properties object?

Comment: If you need to specify a different Serde's as the consumer and the producer  you can specify that when building the KStream (for the consumer) and when publishing to your output topic (for the producer). Let me update my answer to give an example